# Differentiate between NaN input and empty input with an Input of type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I want to use a form input with type="number" and only allow numbers to be entered.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control fc-input"/>
```

I don't have a submit button, instead the value is checked after the input loses focus. However when you use type="number" and a non-number is entered, both the `valueAsNumber` and the `value` attributes of the input will be useless (NaN respectively ""). The problem with this is that I want to differentiate between the user entering an empty string (""), and the user entering a non-number value (e.g. 123abc). When the input is empty I want to execute function a, and if it's just a non-number I want to execute function b (otherwise do c).

Is there a good way to differentiate between NaN input and empty ("") input like this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but why not `if(value === NaN)` and `if(value === "")`?

Comment: Funny thing about NaN is that it is not equal to itself... `NaN === NaN // false`

Comment: @Jordan: The `if(value === NaN)` will always be `false`, no matter what `value` is. Nothing is `===` to `NaN`, including `NaN`.

Comment: @Jordan The problem is that whenever I enter both an empty string (remove all input) and when I enter a NaN value ("abc") the value will always be "", and at the same the the valueAsNumber will always be NaN, therefore I can not differentiate between the two cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is input type of number does a lot of stuff under the covers and the specification for it does not expose the actual invalid value to you. So an empty input and an invalid string look the same. So you need to do some investigation work using `validity`

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");

document.getElementById("num").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var isValid = this.validity.valid;
  var len = this.value.length;

  if (isValid && !len) {
      result.innerHTML = "No value";
  } else if (!isValid) {
      result.innerHTML = "Invalid number";
  } else {
      result.innerHTML = "Valid number: " + this.valueAsNumber;
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Problem with the code above is if you make it required, the empty check will fail. If it is required the if check would need to be

```
if (!isValid && this.validity.valueMissing) {
```

Comment: I was completely unaware of the validity attribute. It does exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: If you are using the validity, then you should use the "input" event instead as all browsers that support validity also support the input event