# Why does the value of an input with type="number" remain 'NaN' after I delete the contents?

Tags: html, angular

Very easy question but too much confused about whats the scope of `input type='number'` field.
Actually working on forms found error during validation of the form.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Demo Number Field" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="demoNumber">
{{demoNumber}} 

<input type="text" placeholder="Demo Text Field" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="demoText">
{{demoText}}
```

When I load the page for the first time these input fields have values of `null` but whenever I fill those fields once and then delete all contents from both fields, the value of `Textfield` is `null` but the value of `numberfield` remains `NAN` instead of `null`. Why is this so? Due to this, the `form` is valid even if number field is empty (after removing content) which is wrong. How can I fix this?

One more thing - why does `numberfield` accept some characters like `e`  but not all characters like `d,f,r`, etc.?

here is plnkr which i have used for demo purpose

<kbd>[Plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/MW3vT4XscWcKrDdAwBoE?p=preview)</kbd>

PS :- Is there any way to restrict user not to allow `e` or something else  in the number field ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26722397/215945

Comment: yups now more clear. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit::** chrome accepts `e`, firefox also accepts `e`. because `e` can exist in the form of 1.1e+10.

However firefox does't allow `e` if its in invalid formats like, `e or 1e` etc. Firefox allows if its in valid format like `1.1e+10`.

**Original answer:**
After the edit and making the text box empty, scope of text field is set to empty string, not null.

Same way, scope of number field is set to empty string. When you try to render it, you will get NaN.

For your second question, I have tried in firefox and it is not accepting any characters like e, f, r etc. They are being shown in red color.

Comment: When I test in Chrome it accepts only `e`, but it does accept it, and the value of the scoped variable remains `NaN` as it should. Pretty weird.

Comment: yups exactly on chrome it accept `e`. strange !! why so ?

Comment: @Naga but i have set the type `number`  not `string` using typescript check my plnkr again.

Comment: @PardeepJain: Bro, I think its not about the type you set on input. Its on the model and automatic type conversion of javascript. If you enter 5, it will be treated as number on the scope. If you remove it, it will be an empty string but not number anymore because of typeconversion.

Comment: @PardeepJain:: edited answer with explanation on why e is allowed. Thanks for pointing this out, I learned something which I didn't knew.

Comment: @NagaSandeep bro i got your first point why `e` only acceptable by browsers. but for second one m still confused. and how can i remove the scope of number field ? i don't want `NAN` after removing contents so what should i do ? BTW thanks for well explanation +1.

Comment: Plunker shows that you are using angular2, which I am not familiar with. But if you want to validate a input type number for empty string, you can just add 'required' on the input tag. If you do custom validation, you can do NaN because required will make sure that the number is not empty. I hope it helps you.

Comment: yups i am using angular2. okay got your point thanks. ill wait for more perfect answer for yesterday otherwise ill mark this one as accepted :p